# PHP - Display user data after a registration

Tags: php

I'm new to the PHP and i can't display some user's information after a successfull registration, how can I do it? I don't really know what to use after the WHERE clause. The registration form works and save data in the DB.

This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE `clienti` (
  `Nome` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Cognome` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Sesso` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `CItta` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Corso` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `DataNascita` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

This is the registration.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "palestra";

try{
    $Nome = $_POST["Nome"];
    $Cognome = $_POST["Cognome"];
    $Email = $_POST["Email"];
    $Password = $_POST["Password"];
    $Sesso = $_POST["Sesso"];
    $Citta = $_POST["Citta"];
    $Corso = $_POST["Corso"];
    $DataNascita = $_POST["DataNascita"];

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `palestra`.`clienti` (`Nome`, `Cognome`, `Email`, `Password`, `Sesso`, `Citta`, `Corso`, `DataNascita`) VALUES (:Nome, :Cognome, :Email, :Password, :Sesso, :Citta, :Corso, :DataNascita)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':Nome', $Nome);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Cognome', $Cognome);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Email', $Email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Password', $Password);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Sesso', $Sesso);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Citta', $Citta);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Corso', $Corso);
    $stmt->bindParam(':DataNascita', $DataNascita);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Registrato correttamente!"); location.href="profile.php"';
    echo '</script>';
    
}catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connessione Fallita"  . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

This is the page with the information that doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "palestra";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Nome, Cognome, Corso FROM clienti WHERE Email=";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> Nome: ". $row["Nome"]. " - Cognome: ". $row["Cognome"]. " - Corso: ". $row["Corso"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to this is simply to display the data directly from the registration page, instead of attempting to transfer to another page.

In that scenario I'd guess your profile.php page is more likely to be useful once the user has actually logged in (rather than just registered). So you'd write:

```
try{
    $Nome = $_POST["Nome"];
    $Cognome = $_POST["Cognome"];
    $Email = $_POST["Email"];
    $Password = $_POST["Password"];
    $Sesso = $_POST["Sesso"];
    $Citta = $_POST["Citta"];
    $Corso = $_POST["Corso"];
    $DataNascita = $_POST["DataNascita"];

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `palestra`.`clienti` (`Nome`, `Cognome`, `Email`, `Password`, `Sesso`, `Citta`, `Corso`, `DataNascita`) VALUES (:Nome, :Cognome, :Email, :Password, :Sesso, :Citta, :Corso, :DataNascita)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':Nome', $Nome);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Cognome', $Cognome);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Email', $Email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Password', $Password);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Sesso', $Sesso);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Citta', $Citta);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Corso', $Corso);
    $stmt->bindParam(':DataNascita', $DataNascita);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    echo "<br> Nome: ".$Nome." - Cognome: ".$Cognome." - Corso: ".$Corso."<br>";
    
}catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connessione Fallita"  . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

---

An alternative way is to transfer the required ID (or email in your case) as a query parameter in the redirect URL, and then retrieve it in the profile page from the $_GET array.

For this, in the registration page you'd write:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Registrato correttamente!"); location.href="profile.php?email=<?php echo urlencode($Email); ?>"';
echo '</script>'
```

Then in profile.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

if (isset($_GET["email"])
{
  $Email = $_GET["email"];

  session_start();

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "palestra";

  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Nome, Cognome, Corso FROM clienti WHERE Email = :Email");
  $stmt->bindParam(':Email', $Email);
  $stmt->execute();
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if ($row) {
    echo "<br> Nome: ". $row["Nome"]. " - Cognome: ". $row["Cognome"]. " - Corso: ". $row["Corso"]. "<br>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
  }
}
else
{
  echo "Error - no profile selected";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

P.S. It made no sense for you to be using PDO in one script, and then mysqli in another. Choose a database library and stick to it. I've used PDO throughout in this answer.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to show a cost if the user choose a determined "Corso"? Maybe with a IF?

Comment: Yes, that sounds straightforward. Where does the cost data come from? P.S. If the answer above helped you, please mark it as accepted. If you have further questions, consider posting a new question on StackOverflow so the whole community can help you, rather than just me.

Comment: Thank you, firstly I'll search for someone who needed what I need, if I don't anything I'll ask :)